# Write file to Windows OS from JavaScript to persist browser configuration

Tags: javascript, windows, file, save

This example allows you to choose where to save a file to disk after clicking the "SAVE TO DISK" button.  However, I'd like to do this automatically without having to choose the file location.  After an event takes place in JavaScript, I'd like to create the file or update the file based on a pre-determined path/file.  How can this be done?

http://pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/test.html

I'm trying to keep track of browser configuration.

Comment: Impossible, you'll have to rethink what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can do this with java, but any writes to users disk is considered major security risk. This should be avoided in any way.

Comment: I am running a stand alone HTML page with JavaScript (I can't use ASP.NET here), and I want to keep configuration persisted while the browser is open.  I think I might have to call a web service (and make a JSON call) and set the configuration value and get the configuration value there.  Unless you can think of an easier way.

Comment: @MacGyver: In that case, you'll want to check out HTML5's sessionStorage and/or localStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant write a file to disc, but you do have a few options:

- [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie)
- [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB)

Comment: found a really good article.  I'm sort of leaning toward the HTML5 storage for what I'm doing.  http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score 6):

It can't be done, for security reasons I'd think were fairly obvious.